# How does Hellsing (2001) relate to Hellsing (2006)?

Tags: hellsing

How does the original Hellsing anime series relate to the newer OVA from 2006?

Is it just a re-release or is there more to it?

Comment: Nothing except for the character names, AFAIK. Hellsing 2001 is completely filler, while 2006 OVA is completely canon. Much like Fullmetal Alchemist (2003) and Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Hellsing (2001)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hellsing_episodes#Hellsing) was based on the manga but contained significant differences, though the character design was similar and the names were the same. The setting was the same as the setting in the manga, but the plot was entirely different.

[Hellsing (2006)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hellsing_episodes#Hellsing_Ultimate) or Hellsing Ultimate was an OVA that shared the same plot as the manga, following it much more closely than Hellsing (2001) did. Animated entries of [*The Dawn*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellsing#Hellsing%3a_The_Dawn), the prequel series to Hellsing, were released with the 8th, 9th, and 10th episodes of Hellsing (2006).